# Error while uploading a file using java

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive api's to upload the new file....While doing so, I get the following error

> You cannot upload content to files of type
>   application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.

I am able to upload the file when I set the mimeType as null...If I set the mimeType as application/octet-stream, I get the above error
Can anyone let me know what are the mimeTypes which can be set?? and also what does that error actually means??

TIA,
VijayRaj

Comment: Can you give us more information as to how you are uploading the files? Are you first uploading the metadata, and the the media in a separate request or are you sending both metadata and media in the same request?

Comment: This is the code I am using....
`com.google.api.services.drive.model.File body = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File(); 
body.setTitle(filename);
body.setMimeType(<mimetype>);
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(<mimetype>, file); resultFile = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are getting this error because you did not register the MIME type `application/octet-stream` as a MIME type of your application in the [Google APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1) project.  If you update those settings with the correct MIME type(s) and extensions, this should work fine.  The code from your comment seems correct.

Comment: Can we write a content to the shortcut file i.e, without mentioning the mime type??

Comment: Shortcut-type files are meant to be shortcut only (e.g no blob content). If you need to add content to a file, you need to specify a MIME type when inserting it.

Comment: Can we update these shortcut files?? I tried to update these shortcut files but their last modified time remains unchanged..

Comment: I tried to update the modified date for the shortcut files using the code `Date d=new Date();
        DateTime now = new DateTime(d.getTime());
        file.setModifiedDate(now);`
while doing so I get Bad request error...any pointers??